# How can I change the background color of a WPF window from a different WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a settings menu in my c# WPF application. How can I change the backround color of one window in a different window?

Comment: you should store it in a view model and settings.

Comment: Did you write any code? You should post the most significant parts

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging messaging with parameters to pass around data between your windows

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/).

The idea is to have your user controls subscribe to events that they would like to respond to.

NOTE:

I do this with viewmodels.
However, I think it is a code-smell when adding this code to user-controls that are meant to have general use regardless of the application employing them.

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```